# How to treat differently exceptions in JSON Methods in a Spring global exception handler?

Tags: json, spring, error-handling

I have a global exception handler used for every exception and I want it to treat different my JSON methods. But I want to keep it centralized.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver{

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest  request, 
                                              HttpServletResponse response,
                                              Object handler, 
                                              Exception ex) {

   // Omitted code like logging, message translation, etc.

    String contentType = response.getContentType();

    //FIXME: This do NOT WORK. contentType will be null
    if(contentType != null && contentType.startsWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)){

            // Add error as a header                                
            modelAndView.setView( new MappingJackson2JsonView() );
    }else{
            // Add error to model   
            modelAndView.setViewName(MyJSPView);                        
    }
}
```

After debugging I see that content type is null and I cant not use it. **How could I distinguish between both calls?**. For testing I coded this pair of methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "jspTest")
public String jspTest(){
    throw new UserMessageException(ErrorMessages.TESTING_ERROR);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "jsonTest", produces = ContentType.JSON)
@ResponseBody
public String jsonTest(){
    throw new UserMessageException(ErrorMessages.TESTING_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.

1. I had mistakenly mixed @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler in an AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver. They are different ways to handle an exception. See [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/)

   So I replaced @ControllerAdvice for @Component and removed @ExceptionHandler. Now the Method handler returns in the handler parameter
2. I used this method:

private static boolean isJson(Object handler){

```
if( ! (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)){
    return false;
}
        
RequestMapping mapping =  ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

for(String mimeType : mapping.produces()){
    if( mimeType.indexOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  != -1 ){
        return true;
    }
}

// Mime types produced does not include  application/json
return false;
```

}